# when I want to insert a data in my directory I have the following error

Tags: ldap

```
0x10 (No such attribute; 00000057:
LdapErr: DSID-0C090E21
comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v2580): 
         adding: cn=BOB JOHN,OU=TI2-PAM-J-A-2017-2018,OU=2017-2018,OU=ETUDIANTS,DC=myiuc,DC=lan
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $info["title"][0] = "STUDENT";
    $info["cn"][0] = "Bob John";
    $info["displayName"][0] = "Bob John";
    $info["givenName"][0] = "Bob John";
    $info["sn"][0] = "noutsa";
    $info["distinguishedName"][0] = "cn=BOB JOHN,OU=TI2-PAM-J-A-2017-2018,OU=2017-2018,OU=ETUDIANTS,DC=myiuc,DC=lan";
    $info["telephonenumber"][0] = "689752145";
    $info["c"][0] = "CM";
    $info["company"][0] = "Institut Universitaire de la Cote";
    $info["mail"] = "bob.john@myiuc.com";
    $info["userPrincipalName"][0] = "bob.john16@myiuc.com";
    $info["sAMAccountName"][0] = "bob.john";
    $info["streetaddress"][0] = "logbessou";
    $info["objectguid"][0] = "wEDfr@14R??!!";
    $info["objectclass"] = ["top","person","organizationalPerson","user","etudiants"];
```